# How to write a trigger to insert data into another table looping another table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I want to write a trigger to insert data into the table `notification_user` for all users in `user` table with timestamp whenever notification add to the `notification` table.

### notification

```
+----+---------+
| id | message |
+----+---------+
```

### user

```
+----+-------+
| id | name |
+----+-------+
```

### notification_user

```
+-----------------+---------+-----------+
| notification_id | user_id | timestamp |
+-----------------+---------+-----------+
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: So there are 3 tables involved? `notification_user`, `user` and `notification`?

Comment: yes @PerlDog,  trigger should be in the `notification` table on insert and data should be added into the `notification_user` table

Comment: Well, then [go ahead](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html). `create trigger FOO after insert on notification for each row begin insert into notification_user ...` would be a good start. Please show your approach and where you got stuck.

Comment: i need to insert it for all users in the `user` table. so it should loop through the all users in `user` table isn't it ?

Comment: It's not clear what exaclty you want (and when you want it). Please improve your odds of getting a helpful answer by providing the structures of the three tables.

Comment: I've updated structure of three tables. I want to run the trigger when adding new records to `notification` table and add new records for `notification_user` table for all users in `user` table

Comment: If there are two user in the `user` table 2 records should be added in to the `notification_user` table whenever i add record to `notification` table

Comment: Please add any relevant information to the question itself. One should not need to read through the comments to undestand the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask: Search, and research and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest.